# How can I set up my 2560x1440 resolution screen to ubuntu 22? It would't recognize the correct resolution, just 1080p

Tags: display, intel-graphics, display-resolution, xrandr

I had ubuntu 20.04 and tried to set up a new screen that's 2560x1440, but the resolution wouldn't be recognized, I tried using xrandr to add a new mode to the HDMI-1 port and it wouldn't work, so I upgraded to ubuntu 22.05 and now the port is named WAYLAND0 and I can't even see the created resolution in the settings. I have a Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 2500 (IVB GT1). When I run xrandr, it shows:

````
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 390mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
leonelbc@leonelbc-Inspiron-660:~$ cvt 2560 1440
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
leonelbc@leonelbc-Inspiron-660:~$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1440" 312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
leonelbc@leonelbc-Inspiron-660:~$ xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 "2560x1440"
leonelbc@leonelbc-Inspiron-660:~$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode 2560x1440
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
leonelbc@leonelbc-Inspiron-660:~$ ```

Any ideas?
````

Comment: are you using a displayport cable to connect to the monitor? Also, xrandr won't work at all with Wayland (which is default on 22.04)

Comment: Hi! I am using a HDMI cable, and thanks, I guess that's why it wouldn't change the resolution. Any recommendations?

Comment: switch to DisplayPort. It seems that your graphics card can't do that resolution on HDMI.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. If my desktop doesn't have a display port, would an adapter solve do the job?

Comment: most likely not